# Gremlin: how to find other edges with the same property

Tags: gremlin

I have a graph with two vertices having id(s) 'a' and 'b'.

gremlin> g.V()

==>v[b]

==>v[a]

There are two edges from 'a' to 'b'.

gremlin> g.E()

==>e[a6b4bead-c161-5a61-d232-abfa2bfad54e][a-LIKES->b]

==>e[10b4bead-a0fc-8d2c-d69f-26b3e9e4c5d8][a-KNOWS->b]

gremlin> g.E().valueMap(true)

==>{id=a6b4bead-c161-5a61-d232-abfa2bfad54e, semantics=social, label=LIKES}

==>{id=10b4bead-a0fc-8d2c-d69f-26b3e9e4c5d8, semantics=social, label=KNOWS}

My question: given an id for one of the edges, I would like to find all other edges with the same value for the property "semantics".  For example, given a.LIKES.id, I would like to execute a query that will return a.KNOWS using the value a.LIKES.semantics.

I started with:

g.E('a6b4bead-c161-5a61-d232-abfa2bfad54e')
 .property('semantics').as('semantics')...this is where I am stuck

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: Do you want to consider all edges in the graph or only edges that are incident to `a` (and/or `b`)?

Comment: only those incident to 'a'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where()` in conjunction with a `by()` modulator will do the job:

```
g.E('a6b4bead-c161-5a61-d232-abfa2bfad54e').as('e').
  outV().inE().
  where(eq('e')).by('semantics'). // return edges with the same semantics property value
  where(neq('e'))                 // ... except the one we started with
```